# How do I make legends in Google Maps with a Google Fusion Tables Layer work?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

i am using Google Fusion Tables and Google Maps to display geographical data (e.g. markers). My map needs to have a legend, for example by inserting a div on top of the map and the layer. As i am not used to work with API of any kind, i got stuck with this legend problem.

I tried several example codes (most of them provided by google), but none worked for me. I guess that the problem of displaying divs on a map has got something to do with either the styling of the map canvas, the div implementation within the body of the html document or with the framework used (google appengine). But this is just guessing. As i am not a professional with coding, i maybe missed a important point. Maybe the folks here can help me out? 
Every hint is appreciated. Thanks.

You can have a look at the code and my example [here (deleted)]. There example includes a code which should display a div, but it doesn't. I've taken it from [here (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42792/1260086).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're using is v2 of the Maps API. You'll want to use code that works with v3 of the Maps API, since that is the version you're using on your site.

Have you tried the sample code here?

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/legend

Copy and paste the legend code from this example into your initialize method, remove the old legend code. If this doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Hey Kathryn , thanks for your answer! I did not know that my sample was made from v2 of the Maps API. I've put in your sample. The outcome is a blank page. Something seems to be wrong with the initialize method, although it seems to be correct, as it works with the original example.

Comment: You might need to make sure the style sheet is downloaded, too, as this sets the size of the map: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved by using the correct Maps API version and by including the rigt stylesheet.